# How to find root parent id of a child from a table in Azure Databricks using Spark/Python/SQL. Note: CONNECT BY/ RECURSIVE CTE are not supported

Tags: sql, azure, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

**Source Table:**

[image]

**Tree Represntation of above table:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide any code that you have tried?

Comment: @RakeshGovindula-MT, Thanks for ur time. Just got the code from this link and its working as expected.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562607/recursive-cte-in-spark-sql