# CTE query to generate new rows based on existing column in spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have created a table(trial).

```
create table trial(
  started int,
  ended int
);

insert into trial values(1, 7),
(5, 6),
(9, 14);

-- select * from trial;
```

Now I want to generate new rows for each row where new row starts from started column value until the new column ('nr') hits the value of ended column.

In SQLSERVER, I can write this to get the desired results.

```
with cte as (
  Select started, ended, started nr from trial
  union all
  Select started, ended, nr+1 from cte
  where nr<ended
)
Select started, ended, nr from cte
order by started;
```

Output:

| started | ended | nr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 | 1 |
| 1 | 7 | 2 |
| 1 | 7 | 3 |
| 1 | 7 | 4 |
| 1 | 7 | 5 |
| 1 | 7 | 6 |
| 1 | 7 | 7 |
| 5 | 6 | 6 |
| 5 | 6 | 5 |
| 9 | 14 | 9 |
| 9 | 14 | 10 |
| 9 | 14 | 11 |
| 9 | 14 | 12 |
| 9 | 14 | 13 |
| 9 | 14 | 14 |

Currently I'm getting this error while using same query.

[image: Screenshot of error message]

How can I achieve the same results in spark SQL and pyspark using CTE?
Can we write a code which helps to achieve the same?

Comment: Recursivity using CTE is not available in spark sql.  
see if it helps : https://medium.com/globant/how-to-implement-recursive-queries-in-spark-3d26f7ed3bc9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [recursive cte in spark SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52562607/recursive-cte-in-spark-sql)

Comment: with current understanding I'll use udf to generate numbers in between and explode it go get desired results. Is there any better way if so what can be code to achieve it efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sequence` operation for this.

```sql
select 
  started, 
  ended,
  explode(sequence(started, ended)) as nr
from trial
```

Comment: Figured it out just now. Thanks alot Emma.